# How to correctly configure AAD App Registration and WebAPI to allow [Authorize]

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, authorize

I have 2 AAD app registrations, one for a desktop client, the other for a web API. I have configured the Authentications as per the Microsoft QuickStart to use microsoft.identity.client and microsoft.identity.client.broker to authenticate and get a token. This seems to work correctly. The web api uses the following for authentication:

`builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));`

I have also configured the Enterprise applications is AAD.

Without the [Authorize] in the web api controller, I can use the desktop app to get data from the web api with a call such as:

```
GetHttpContentWithToken(APIEndpoint, authResult.AccessToken)
```

However, as soon as add the [Authorize] to the controller, I cant get any data back. In fact, when I run the debugger, it doesn't seem like the call ever makes it to the controller.

If I look at the ILogger output (when [Authorize] is not present) it seems the token is valid.

[image]

I'm not sure where to go from here. Maybe I don't have the correct authentication provider in the Program.cs of the web api. Or maybe I don't have the correct packages. I think I have the correct scopes configured. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can find a sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#web-api). Per my understanding, you may need to set in appsettings.json of your web api with configuration `"AzureAd": { "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/","ClientId": "aad_client_id","TenantId": "tenant_id","Audience": "api://aad_client_id" },`, and in your client, you also need to set the scope for obtaining access token like `api://aad_client_id/your_scope_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below steps to Configure AAD App Registration and `WebAPI` to allow `[Authorize]`.

I have taken references the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis).

- After registering the App in AAD, we need to do the below setting in `Expose an API` for both registered Applications.

[image]

[image]

- Add Scope for `Admins` only or `Admins and Users`.

[image]

Make sure you have added the `Client Application`.

[image]

- I have created an `ASP.NET Core WebAPI 6.0`.
- In the Connected Services, add the `Microsoft identity platform` service dependency.

[image]

- Select the App which you have added the `Client Application`.

[image]

- With this, `Redirect URI` will be added in the selected App Registration.

Thanks @Tiny Wang for the comment.

Yes, as mentioned by Tiny Wang, we need to add the Scopes as well.

***My `appsettings.json`:***

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "******.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "**********",
    "ClientId": "**********",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Scopes": "AllMemberAPI.All",
    "ClientSecret": "Client secret from app-registration. Check user secrets/azure portal.",
    "ClientCertificates": []
  }
}
```

***My `.csproj` file:***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="6.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.24.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="1.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

- First, we need to Authenticate the user. Check whether the user is authenticated or not.
- To know more about the Authentication middleware, we can download the sample code from the `App Registration` => `Quickstart`.

[image]