# How can i restrict access to an Azure app service?

Tags: azure, access-control

I have an Azure app service. Now i want to restrict access to all users except to a
certain few users.

I have tried to give access via the Access Control (IAM), what do is i select ,"Add role
assignment" and if i do I make the user a contributor.
Meanwhile any other user can come in and just click on the default domain url and they can
get in ?

Is there an easy way of doing this ?

Comment: Have you tried by restricting the IP address in the Networking section? [Image](https://i.imgur.com/1TQrRGL.png)

Comment: I have but  some users use dhcp so the address changes on a daily basis. I was wanting to use their Entra email address ?

Comment: `except to a certain few users` To whom you wan tto give access ?

Comment: Instead of IPAddress you can also use [Virtual Network](https://i.imgur.com/2JsrCZ0.png) and create a rule.

Comment: One more option is to authenticate the app using Azure AD and assign the users to the `User and Groups`.Users who have the assignment can only login and access the application.

Answer (score 0):

To allow only specific users to access the App Service, we can use `Microsoft Entra ID`(Azure Active Directory) and authenticate the Users.

Check the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad) to Configure your App Service to use Microsoft Entra sign-in.

Also refer SO Threads  [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77065090/19648279) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75977079/19648279) to configure Microsoft Identity Platform from Connected Services in Visual Studio

- Use `Connected Services` to configure for an existing app.

> restrict access to all users except to a certain few users.

Navigate to the `Microsoft Entra ID` => `App registrations` => select your App => `App roles` => click on `How do I assign App roles` => `Enterprise applications`

[image]

- Enable the `Assignment required` option in `Properties` section and `Save`.

[image]

- Select `Users and groups` option => click on `Add user/group`
- Search and assign the Users whom you want to give access to the app and `Assign`.

[image]

Users without access permission will get the below error.

> ```cs
> You don't have access to this Your sign-in was successful but you don't have permission to access this resource.
> ```

> ```cs
> Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
>
> AADSTS50105: Your administrator has configured the application RestrictAccess ('****') to block users unless they are specifically granted ('assigned') access to the application. The signed in user '' is blocked because they are not a direct member of a group with access, nor had access directly assigned by an administrator. Please contact your administrator to assign access to this application.
> ```

***User with access permission***

[image]

Comment: I cant seem to see my app in the app registration. I have an identity set ?

Comment: Have you configured it from Visual Studio.If not you need to create it manually.

Comment: I have deployed it from visual studio.  and then created an identity in Azure

Comment: Check under [All Applications](https://i.imgur.com/JRMHF6G.png)

Comment: @Sally - Are you able to see the App?

Comment: No i still cant see the app

Comment: Create app manually in AD and configure your code inlocal with these AD  credentials

Comment: I will try that and let you know .

Comment: Any update on this? Are you still facing the issure?